# RingCentral on Ubuntu via Wine

Tags: wine

I'm trying to get RingCentral for Windows, working. I've got it to install and load but I have a consistent crash that no amount of googling has been able to help me with:

Distro: Ubuntu 15.10

wine --version: wine-1.6.2

Steps to Recreate:

1. download msi: http://downloads.ringcentral.com/sp/RingCentralForWindows
2. pol > install > Install program not listed
3. components: vcrun2010, dotnet4
4. continue > make shortcut for softphone.exe
5. open program > login > crash

Below is a redacted copy of my log:

```
.... # many many more fixme:d3d

fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsW (0x3321e8c, (nil), {f7b697a3-4db5-4d3b-be71-c4d284e6592f}, 7, 0x34dc968, (null), (null), 0x352d940,): stub
fixme:process:GetNumaHighestNodeNumber (0x32c4ec): stub
fixme:dbghelp_msc:pdb_parse_cmd_string Couldn't evaluate "$T0 .raSearch = $eip $T0 ^ = $esp $T0 4 + = " => get_zvalue: no value found (.raSearch)
fixme:process:GetNumaHighestNodeNumber (0x57fd7c0): stub
15:04:26.748 os_core_win32. !pjlib 2.1 for win32 initialized
15:04:26.750 sip_endpoint.c  .Creating endpoint instance...
15:04:26.750          pjlib  .select() I/O Queue created (0537CF38)
15:04:26.751 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-msg-print" registered
15:04:26.751 sip_transport.  .Transport manager created.
15:04:26.751   pjsua_core.c  .PJSUA state changed: NULL --> CREATED


Aborted! 2016-Jan-05 15:07:20
Exception 
>>>
Halt on unexpected exception at location QtModanoApp::notify
Windows Exception EXCEPTION_MS_CPP (0xe06d7363) at 0x7B8395FC; Exception type 'Concurrency::scheduler_resource_allocation_error' info 'Unknown exception'
 * stack trace * 
<undef>
<undef>
<undef>
<undef>
<undef>
<undef>
<undef>
<undef>
<undef>
<undef>

<<<
ESS::Assertion in thread main (9) @ ..\..\..\src\Utils\ErrorsSubsystem.cpp:394 in void __cdecl ESS::HaltOnUnexpected(const struct Utils::ExceptionInfo &,const class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > &)
* Stack trace *
<Stack trace not available on current OS version!>
fixme:dbghelp_msc:pdb_parse_cmd_string Couldn't evaluate "$T0 .raSearch = $eip $T0 ^ = $esp $T0 4 + =  $20 $T0 216 - ^ =  $22 $T0 220 - ^ =  $23 $T0 224 - ^ =  $24 $T0 228 - ^ = " => get_zvalue: no value found (.raSearch)
fixme:dbghelp_msc:pdb_parse_cmd_string Couldn't evaluate "$T0 .raSearch = $eip $T0 ^ = $esp $T0 4 + =  $20 $T0 216 - ^ =  $22 $T0 220 - ^ =  $23 $T0 224 - ^ =  $24 $T0 228 - ^ = " => get_zvalue: no value found (.raSearch)
err:secur32:SECUR32_initSchannelSP TLS library not found, SSL connections will fail
fixme:thread:GetThreadPreferredUILanguages 56, 0x33f9f0, 0x33fa04 0x33f9f8
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x33f448 (nil)): stub
fixme:console:GetConsoleProcessList (0x33fc80,1): stub
fixme:system:SetProcessDPIAware stub!
fixme:ole:RemUnknown_QueryInterface No interface for iid {00000019-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
fixme:wtsapi:WTSQuerySessionInformationW Stub (nil) 0xffffffff 4 0x86e648 0x86e638
```

I'm not sure how to proceed. Any pointers would be really helpful - I need to get this software running otherwise I'll be forced to work on Windows.

Comment: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=32478 says that even if you manage to install it it will freeze.

Comment: Try to run it [with the latest Wine](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ubuntu/ppa), you may also check this [short troubleshooting list](https://www.winehq.org/docs/wineusr-guide/bugs). If neither would work, [report a bug](https://bugs.winehq.org/).

Comment: @Braiam Given that I'm the one that wrote that, yes. I'm aware.

Comment: Thanks @Hi-Angel I'll try those two out and update my post.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't RingCentral just a rebranded Zoom? Try Zoom's native Linux client (works in my Ubuntu 15.04 for a long time with updates that were coming out along the way) available for dl at http://zoom.us/download

Once in a meeting those 2 clients seem to look the same.

Comment: I confirm it works **very well** on archlinux. Installed it from the [aur](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/zoom/) `sudo aura -As zoom`. I was using my mobile client or a windows vm, but it is way better with the native client. Even screen sharing works. <3

Comment: Zoom works fine on Linux Mint 18 but it does not recognize some meeting IDs generated on RingCentral (while it works well with others).

Answer (score 1):

I got this working on 16.04 Gnome and PlayonLinux, both for sending and receiving calls.

For PlayonLinux: (Wine is already installed on 16.04)

```
wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_trusty.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

Install RingCentral(7.0.7) through playonlinux (not wine) as a 32 bit program, setting softphone.exe as your shortcut. Then install vcrun2013 and dotnet45 components. Set wine configuration for 1.9.24.

Ringcentral 7.0.7:
http://downloads.ringcentral.com/sp/RingCentralForWindows-7.0.7.msi

Just remember to go into your ringcentral account and activate the computer you installed this on so it's authorized to actually call instead of "RingOut".

Comment: I didn't use their service for too long. There are far better, cheaper, web-based (and therefore OS independent) services out there. I'm using bettervoice.com which I highly recommend.

Comment: Believe me, I'd rather use just about anything else, but my employer uses this, so I have to.

Comment: UPDATE: So today I logged in and it wouldn't let me do anything up update to the latest version. I made sure to not launch after installation and just went through the normal update process and it works flawlessly. Using 8.4.5 now.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working with an older version of RingCentral (7.0.7):

```
wine: 1.9
vcrun2013
dotnet45
```

It only functioned as Ringout mode. Making it useless.

Comment: I see [they have something named «open case»](http://success.ringcentral.com/RCContactSupp?src=). I'd advice you to use that to report a bug **to them** in particular. Tell then that their soft doesn't have Ubuntu version, which is sucks, so they need to either fix wine so that it would work, or build a GNU/Linux version. Ofc they won't do anything right now, but they have to hear their customers, because that's how it works. And btw, report the bug to wine team anyway — they need to know the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I have already followed the routes that they have offered ie, feature suggestion forums, and complaint process. They just flat out refused to support the platform, which is understandable but unfortunate.

Comment: I managed to sign-up with Google account; the page seems to be deleted. Could you give the link to your request? Or was this one the one you were talking about?

Comment: Download link: http://downloads.ringcentral.com/sp/RingCentralForWindows-7.0.7.msi

Comment: Discussion page: https://devcommunity.ringcentral.com/ringcentraldev/topics/soft_phone_for_linux_ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I got it working on Ubuntu mate 16.04.  Wine 1.9.10. I had to use the 7.0.7 msi to install it, but it prompted me to download it when I tried to install 8.0.6 and it didn't work.  Softphone works and everything.  I got the newest wine from their repository.  Downloaded RingCentralForWindows.msi from their website. ran it with

```
wine msiexec /i RingCentralForWindows-8.0.6.msi
```

It ran through and installed whatever dependencies weren't installed.  Then promptly told me it wasn't able to run, and gave me a link to download 7.0.7.  Ran through the same process.  Everything installed fine and it works.  You have to deauthorize whatever other computer you were using RingCentral on through their website though.  The softphone will only work on one machine at any given time.

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer? It looks more like a comment to [this earlier answer](/q/718346/175814).

Comment: Could you include instructions? As @DavidFoerster mentioned, this is more like a comment. The more detail the better!

Comment: Sorry, my first time posting on this site.  Wasn't paying attention.  I'm editing the original.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work in ArchLinux by installing in Crossover with MS Visual C++ 2013, msls31, Core fonts, visual basic runtime, MSXML and .NET 4.0.

You might not need the VBR.